# xamarin ListView den id alma olayı

Tags: forms, xamarin, android-listview, selecteditem, displayalert

After long efforts, I managed to pull data from the api;
When I compile and click on ListVeiw1 screen, I can't get ip or name,
What is the solution?
Thanks.

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" ItemSelected="ListView1_ItemSelected" x:Name="ListView1".....

private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<TodoItem> itemsNew = new List<TodoItem>();
            using (var ic = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await ic.GetAsync("http://adress.com/api/items"))
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    itemsNew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TodoItem>>(content);                 
                    ListView1.ItemsSource = itemsNew;
                }
            }
        }


  private void ListView1_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     string myname = e.SelectedItem.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: "I can't get ip or name" - what does this mean?  Are you saying your ListView is not showing any data?  Please be specific about the exact problem you are having.  You have not shown your `ItemTemplate` or the definition of `TodoItem` so its very difficult to provide advice.

Answer (score -1):

you need to **cast** the `SelectedItem` to the correct **type** before you can access its properties

```
private void ListView1_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var item = (TodoItem)e.SelectedItem;
   // now you can access any properties of item
}
```

Comment: Jason, my dear friend
This brought everything of my chosen one, I need to get his name or ID number from it, originally I was stuck there

var item = (TodoItem)e.SelectedItem;
             DisplayAlert("Selected", item.ToString(), "OK");

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  Are you still having problems?  Or is your problem solved?